# VS2010 T-SQL editor color problem

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2010

My background color in VS is set to black, the problem is that the numeric sql types also (by dafault I guess) are set to black, so I can not see them. Under what name are associated numeric types in "Fonts and Colors" options menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type names (e.g., `bigint`) are colored as **Keyword**. The numeric literals (e.g., `500`) are colored as **Number**.

Comment: Thanks. In "fonts and colors" they were set to "default" and looked fine (with green color), but in TSQL editor they were displayed as black (dont know why). When i explicitly set them to "green" they showed up.

Comment: Wow, i dint expect this question to have been asked and answered! +1